# ERROR: COPY file signature not recognized - Postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am using Postgresql 9.6 COPY BINARY Command to dump a table

```
psql -h  $HOSTNAME -U $USERNAME -d $DBNAME  -qAt -c "COPY ( SELECT  co1,col2,col3   FROM tableName) TO STDOUT WITH BINARY" > fileName.dat
```

And using following command to restore

```
psql  -U $USERNAME  -d $DBNAME  -qAt -c "COPY BINARY tableName(col1,col2,col3) FROM 'fileName.dat'"
```

I am getting the following error.
ERROR:  COPY file signature not recognized.

This used to work fine in Postgresql 9.4 , am i missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I was having ./~psqlrc file , so every time psql command use to run it use to prepend the psqlrc output to the .dat file generated because of which while restoring the error was coming saying.
**ERROR: COPY file signature not recognized**
So using -X option finally solved my problem.

**Dump Command:**

```
psql -h  $HOSTNAME -U $USERNAME -d $DBNAME  -XqAt -c "COPY ( SELECT  co1,col2,col3   FROM tableName) TO STDOUT WITH BINARY" > fileName.dat
```

**Restore Command**

```
  psql  -U $USERNAME  -d $DBNAME  -qAt -c "COPY BINARY tableName(col1,col2,col3) FROM 'fileName.dat'"
```